# .net core, how do i kill a thread without the thread.Abort method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, thread-safety

In my code, i have to run a method from a third-part library that may cause my program to freeze.

To avoid this issue, i thought about running this method in a separate thread, wait for the thread to terminate unless too much time have elapsed using the thread.join function and if the thread did not terminate itself, kill it.

A solution would be to do as following :

```
   Thread MyThread;

   MyThread= new Thread(() => 
   {
       try
       {
           ThirdPartyMethod();
       }
       catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
       {
           Thread.ResetAbort();
       }
   );
   MyThread.Start();

   if !MyThread.join(10000)
     MyThread.Abort();
```

Problem is Thread.Abort is obsolete On .NET 5 and later versions, do you know an other way to kill it ? I have read about process.kill but i'm not sure on how to use it.

Edit : i've tried cooperative cancellation but it won't work here since the thread may be frozen

```
var CanceltokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = CanceltokenSource.Token;
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  ThirdPartyMethod(); // this method can potentially freeze the thread so we won't be able to do a proper cleaning
  if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    // another thread decided to cancel
    // do some cleaning
    // unreachable if the thread is frozen
  }
}, ct);
// Can't wait anymore => cancel this task 
if (!myTask.Wait(3000))
{
  CanceltokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

The real issue is letting a thread alive while doing nothing except using resources. This is why i need a way to kill it after a timeout.

Comment: There’s no reliable way to cancel a thread

Comment: The reason `Thread.Abort` is obsolete is because years of experience with APIs like that suggests that there's no *safe* way to do this without possibly leaving the entire process in an unsafe/inconsistent state. The only safe way, and the only way new APIs approach this is to use *cooperative* cancellation where the running code checks for cancellation at points at which it is *safe* to abandon the work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CancellationToken. Here is a small example:

```
    var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // do some heavy work here
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // another thread decided to cancel
                Console.WriteLine("task canceled");
                break;
            }
        }
    }, ct);
    // Can't wait anymore => cancel this task 
    ts.Cancel();
```

see the microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/thread-abort-obsolete

Comment: thanks for the hint but the way i understand this is i would need to pass the cancellation token to the third-party method that may freeze so that it can monitor the token and stop whenever a cancellation is requested. Problem is i don't have any access to the source code of this method so i won't be able to pass the token. Did i miss something ?

Comment: I changed my example i hope this is more clear.

Comment: i have edited my question but this won't solve the problem since the thread is going to be frozen so it won't be able to see the change in the token

Answer (score -1):

See this Reference for a workaround from Microsoft regarding SYSLIB0006 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0006

```
void ProcessPendingWorkItemsNew(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (QueryIsMoreWorkPending())
    {
        // If the CancellationToken is marked as "needs to cancel",
        // this will throw the appropriate exception.
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        WorkItem work = DequeueWorkItem();
        ProcessWorkItem(work);
    }
}
```